# Can't Override onPostExecute() method in AsyncTask Class or get it to trigger

Tags: java, android, methods, overriding, android-asynctask

I am having trouble getting the `onPostExecute()` method to call when running an `AsyncTask`. When I try to set up my class extending `AsyncTask` in which the `onPostExecute()` is overridden I get the following build error.

> 'The method onPostExecute() of type AsyncTaskExampleActivity must
>   override or implement a supertype method'

I have tried getting rid of the `@Override` annotation. This gets rid of the build error but the method still does not execute. If any one would be so kind as to point out what I'm overlooking I would greatly appreciated it.

Code:

```
package com.asynctaskexample;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class AsyncTaskExampleActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

AsyncTaskExampleActivity(){
super();
    }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

[`OnPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) takes an argument *(the object you return from `doInBackground()`)*. Change it to `protected void onPostExecute(Void v)`. If you don't provide the argument, the method signatures do not match and the override annotation starts to complain that there is no function to override with this signature.

Answer (score 24):

Try:

In the class try right click `Source -> Override/Implement methods..` and look for the `onPostExecute()` method. It will give you complete method with all types of arguments should it get.

Comment: In Android Studio you can go to menu Code -> Override Methods (Ctrl + O)

Comment: On the new version, Right Click -> Generate -> Override methods

Answer (score 0):

if you want your onPostExecute() to be overitten, simply use what was returned in your doInBackground() as an object in your onPostExecute().

For example...

```
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void...args0){
        // your code here...
        return value;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(void value){
        //code to run
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add  super.onPostExecute() method. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing)
{
   super.onPostExecute(nothing);
}
```

EDIT:
Guys, I have no idea why you are downvoting the answer. The questioner is missing an argument of `onPostExecute()` method and doesn't have a supertype method implemented. Thats's the reason I posted this answer.

Comment: Why should he add it? Would you please clarify reasons to?