# Update ViewFlipper every 60 seconds

Tags: android, android-asynctask, viewflipper

In my app, every 60 seconds I get updates from a website. I get this updates in background using a `AsyncTask`. Here is my code :

```
update = new Timer();
        update.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        updateItems();
                    }
                });
            }

        }, 30000, 60000);
```

where `updateItems()` method is :

```
public void updateItems() {
        System.out.println("Every 60 sec getItems");
        new DownloadTask().execute();
    }
```

---

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPostExecute(Void... args) {
            System.out.println("Download finished");
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

            try {
                UpdateItems();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

In `UpdateItems()` I save all the updated images on SDcard. The problem is the `onPostExecute()` is not called after `doInBackground()` because I don't get the message  "Download finished". On this method I want to update the ViewFlipper that is flipping and like this it is changed at second call of `updateitems()`. Have anyone any idea why I have this problem?

EDIT:

```
public void UpdateItems() throws Exception {

        String t = myPrefs.getString(TIME + idPlaylist, "time");
        String d = myPrefs.getString(DATE + idPlaylist, "date");
        String data_download = myPrefs.getString(DATA_DOWNLOAD + idPlaylist,
                "00000000");

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String link = "some link where I send the last download date";
            System.out.println("trimit " + link);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                /* Checking response */
                if (response != null) {
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response
                            .getEntity());
                    System.out
                            .println("Rezultat de la server :" + responseBody);

                    String jsonString = responseBody.toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                    String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                    System.out.println("Status " + status);

                    if (status == "true") {
                        System.out.println("get updates");
                        GetItems();

                        updated = true;
                        dataupdate = new String[jArray.length()];
                        data = new String[jArray.length()];
                        time = new String[jArray.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("last update : " + lastupdate[i]);

                            String[] separated = lastupdate[i].split(" ");
                            data[i] = separated[0];
                            time[i] = separated[1];

                            dataupdate[i] = lastupdate[i].replace("-", "");
                            dataupdate[i] = dataupdate[i].replace(":", "");
                            dataupdate[i] = dataupdate[i].replace(" ", "");

                            System.out.println("data ultimului download "
                                    + data_download + "\ndata update "
                                    + dataupdate[i]);

                            if (Long.valueOf(dataupdate[i]) > Long
                                    .valueOf(data_download)) {
                                System.out.println("image update");
                                saveImageToSDcard(url[i], i);
                                if (target[i].endsWith(".mp4")) {
                                    System.out.println("video de downloadat");
                                    try {
                                        saveVideoToSDcard(target[i], i);
                                        path[i] = Environment
                                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                + "/BouyguesVideos"
                                                + idPlaylist
                                                + "/" + "Video" + idPhotos[i];
                                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                                        System.out.println("Socket timeout");
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                } else
                                    path[i] = target[i];
                            } else
                                System.out.println("image not update");
                        }

                        String actual = dataupdate[0];
                        int indexmax = 0;
                        for (int k = 1; k < jArray.length(); k++) {
                            if (Long.valueOf(dataupdate[k]) > Long
                                    .valueOf(actual)) {
                                actual = dataupdate[k];
                                indexmax = k;
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("max " + actual);

                        prefsEditor
                                .putString(DATE + idPlaylist, data[indexmax]);
                        prefsEditor
                                .putString(TIME + idPlaylist, time[indexmax]);
                        prefsEditor.putString(DATA_DOWNLOAD + idPlaylist,
                                actual);
                        prefsEditor.commit();

                        File f = new File(
                                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + "/BouyguesImages" + idPlaylist + "/");
                        File[] files = f.listFiles();

                        System.out
                                .println("pe card avem " + files.length
                                        + " fisiere" + " iar online "
                                        + jArray.length());

                        if (files.length != jArray.length()) {
                            System.out.println("imagini adaugate sau sterse");

                            for (int k = 0; k < jArray.length(); k++) {
                                System.out.println("imagini pe site "
                                        + idPhotos[k] + namePhotos[k]);
                                ok = false;
                                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                                    System.out.println("comparam "
                                            + files[i].getName() + " cu "
                                            + idPhotos[k] + namePhotos[k]);
                                    if (files[i].getName().equals(
                                            idPhotos[k] + namePhotos[k])) {
                                        System.out.println("exista");
                                        i = files.length;
                                        ok = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (ok == false) {
                                    System.out
                                            .println("not exist-must save now");
                                    try {
                                        saveImageToSDcard(url[k], k);
                                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    if (target[k].endsWith(".mp4")) {
                                        try {
                                            saveVideoToSDcard(target[k], k);
                                            path[k] = Environment
                                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                    + "/BouyguesVideos"
                                                    + idPlaylist
                                                    + "/"
                                                    + "Video" + idPhotos[k];

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                        for (int k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
                            System.out.println("imagini deja salvate "
                                    + files[k].getName());
                            ok = false;
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                System.out.println("comparam "
                                        + files[k].getName() + " cu "
                                        + idPhotos[i] + namePhotos[i]);
                                if (files[k].getName().equals(
                                        idPhotos[i] + namePhotos[i])) {
                                    System.out.println("exista");
                                    i = jArray.length();
                                    ok = true;
                                }
                            }

                            if (ok == false) {
                                System.out.println("delete- not exist more");
                                files[k].delete();
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("no updates");
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Replace `e1.printStackTrace();` with `Log.e("YourTag", "UpdateItems Exception", e1 );`. Run the program and check your LogCat for the exception - if there is one, then post it here.

Comment: I don't get any error on LogCat, I receive only the message that I post on UpdateItems() method.

Comment: Could you add the code for `UpdateItems()` then?

Comment: I edited to my question. It is a little big :)

Comment: Try `System.out.println("Update done");` as the very last thing that `UpdateItems()`does (after all your try/catch stuff) and check if that gets printed.

Comment: I get the message "Update done".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the `@Override` over the onPostExecute and doInBackground (to be sure they're both correctly overriden).

I think it will have something to do with this.

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ...
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object object) {
    ....
    }
```

More details here: [Can't Override onPostExecute() method in AsyncTask Class or get it to trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356243/cant-override-onpostexecute-method-in-asynctask-class-or-get-it-to-trigger)

Comment: I can't put @Override for onPostExecute, I get this error : "The method onPostExecute(Void...) of type ViewPlaylist.DownloadTask must override or implement a supertype method" . And, how to call super for doInBackground?

Comment: Then there you have your problem. Your not overriding the correct method, that why it doesn't get called!

Answer (score 0):

Its looping.

updateItems creates download tasks calls update items creates download task call... etc.

Comment: he edited his question, the previous code posted would have looped.