# Async task does not let me override onPostExecute (method does not override method from it's superclass)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm creating an app that grabs list of playlists on YouTube. It used to be a list of videos, but i've changed the code and now it did not let me override that method.

My understanding is that i should change the "extends AsyncTask" with the new Playlist value instead of Video as it was before, but it still did not work.

it was:

```
public abstract class GetPlaylistAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Pair<String, List<Video>>> {
```

and now is:

```
public abstract class GetPlaylistAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Pair<String, List<Playlist>>> {
```

This is where is the error:

```
mPlaylist = new Playlist(mPlaylistId);
initAdapter(mPlaylist);
new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi, mTitle, mSearchQuery) {
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Playlist>> result) {
        handleGetPlaylistResult(mPlaylist, result);
    }
}.execute(mPlaylist.playlistId, mPlaylist.getNextPageToken());
```

And this is the AsyncTask:

```
public abstract class GetPlaylistAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Pair<String, List<Playlist>>> {
    private static final String TAG = "GetPlaylistAsyncTask";
    private static final Long YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS = 50L;

    private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART = "snippet,contentDetails,statistics"; // video resource properties that the response will include.
    private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS = "items(id,snippet(title,description,thumbnails/high),contentDetails/duration,statistics)"; // selector specifying which fields to include in a partial response.

    private YouTube mYouTubeDataApi;
    private String mTitle;
    private String mSearchQuery;

    public GetPlaylistAsyncTask(YouTube api, String title, String searchQuery) {
        mYouTubeDataApi = api;
        mTitle = title;
        mSearchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected Pair<String, List<Playlist>> doInBackground(String... params) {

        SearchListResponse searchResponse;
        try {
            YouTube.Search.List search = mYouTubeDataApi.search().list("id,snippet");

            search.setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY);
            search.setQ(mTitle + " " + mSearchQuery);

            search.setType("video");
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS);
            searchResponse = search.execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        if (searchResponse == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get playlist");
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList videoIds = new ArrayList();

        for (SearchResult item : searchResponse.getItems()) {
            videoIds.add(item.getId().getVideoId());
        }
        VideoListResponse videoListResponse = null;
        try {
            videoListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.videos()
                    .list(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART)
                    .setFields(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS)
                    .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                    .setId(TextUtils.join(",", videoIds)).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Pair(searchResponse.getNextPageToken(), videoListResponse.getItems());
    }
}
```

i don't get what is wrong on my code, i'll appreciate if you can point me on the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: method does not override method from it's superclass

Comment: change `public` to `protected`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured it out. The "onPostExecute" takes the object that doInBackground returns, as this post says:

[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356243/cant-override-onpostexecute-method-in-asynctask-class-or-get-it-to-trigger)

Thanks to all for your answers, especially to @Enzokie

Answer (score 0):

Just change `public` to `protected` since `onPostExecute` is not public by design.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Playlist>> result) {
        handleGetPlaylistResult(mPlaylist, result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! changed it and rebuild, the error is still on the @Override

Comment: do you have teamviewer? so that I can look at the code. Just send me message in my email and I will try to figure it out or visit me in the chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82392/regular-chat.